# Octobercms - Getting frontend user avatar

Tags: php, octobercms, avatar

So i'm trying to gererate a frontend user list, but i'm having trouble reaching the avatar url.

i'm able to get all user names but when i try to do the same with the profile picture the fallback is shown. 
The `{{ user.avatar.url }}` is working on the user page when someone is signed in.

I've tried to look for the query used on the backend to get the user avatar on the preview, but i was not able to find it.

I don't know if this is relevant but i'm using https://octobercms.com/plugin/netsti-uploader for frontend users to upload their avatars. It's working since if i upload it on the frontend the backend user preview shows the right avatar

This is what i am using to get all users:

CODE:

```
use October\Rain\Auth\Models\User;

function onInit() {
    $this['activatedUsers'] = User::whereIsActivated(true)->get();
}
```

MARKUP

```
<div>
{% for user in activatedUsers %}
    <div class="card list">
        {% if user.avatar %}
            <img class="userimg" src="{{ user.avatar.url }}">
        {% else %}
            <img class="userimg" src="assets/images/user.png">
        {% endif %}
            <p class="name"><span class="rank-title">NAME</span><br>{{ user.name }}&nbsp;{{ user.surname }}</p>
        {% if user.last_login %}
            <p><span class="rank-title">LAST UPDATE</span><br>{{ user.last_login }}</p>
        {%endif%}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use it like that.

```
use RainLab\User\Models\User;

function onInit() {
    $this['activatedUsers'] = User::whereIsActivated(true)->get();
}
```

Markup

```
{% for user in activatedUsers %}
    <div class="card list">
    {{ user.avatar.path }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @MikeStardust You may want to use the `geThumb()` method, which enables you to create a thumbnail with specific dimension  - See answer below

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [October\Rain\Database\Attach\File](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/october/rain/database/attach/file) class to see available methods :

`getThumb($w,$h,$options)` - Generates and returns a thumbnail path

`getPath()` - Returns the public address to access the file

`getLocalPath()` - Returns a local path to this file. If the file is stored remotely,it will be downloaded to a temporary directory.

`getDiskPath()` - Returns the path to the file, relative to the storage disk

e.g :

`{{user.avatar.getThumb(200,200, { mode : 'crop' } )}}`

Answer (score 0):

install "Frontend File Uploader for Model" plugin

insert `{% component 'imageUploader' %}` in your markup

insert

```
function onInit()
{
    $user = Auth::getUser();
    if($user){
        $component = $this->addComponent(
            'NetSTI\Uploader\Components\ImageUploader',
            'imageUploader',
            ['modelClass'=>'RainLab\User\Models\User','modelKeyColumn'=>'avatar', 'deferredBinding' => false]
        );

        $component->bindModel('avatar', $user);
    }
}
```

on your code section

Answer (score 0):

You can query the backend user model with with '*avatar*'.

```php
use Backend\Models\User;

...
$user = User::where('id', $author_id)->with('avatar')->first();
...
```

```
<h1>{{ user.avatar.path }}</h1>
```